Operations on sets with nowhere dense boundary
I am trying to prove what operations are allowed on sets with nowhere dense boundaries (i.e. $A$ such that $\operatorname{int}(\partial A) = \emptyset$).
The complement of a set with nowhere dense boundary also is a set with nowhere dense boundary, since a set and its complement share the same boundary.
I don't seem to be able to prove whether the intersection (or the union) of two such sets gives another set with nowhere dense boundary or not. Ideas?

If $A$ and $B$ both have nowhere dense boundaries, then,
$$\begin{split}
\partial(A \cup B) &= \overline{A \cup B} \setminus \text{int}(A \cup B)\\
&= (\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) \setminus \text{int}(A \cup B)\\
&\subset (\overline{A} \setminus \text{int}(A)) \cup (\overline{B} \setminus \text{int}(B))\\
&= \partial A \cup \partial B
\end{split}$$
The union of two nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense, so $A \cup B$ has nowhere dense boundary. Now, the sets with nowhere dense boundaries are closed under taking complements and unions, and thus also closed under taking intersections.

Union of two nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense and a subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense. Thanks! These sets form a Boolean algebra as I suspected. :-D
